# Add a GET variable to my existing URL through JQuery without page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple question about adding a GET variable on my existing URL.

The link is `http://www.mylink.com/page`

What I want to add is: `http://www.mylink.com/page?/var=Value of the Variable`

This addition of GET variable is triggered through links on the page. If the link is clicked on the page, it should add the GET variable, if some other link is clicked, it should assume that no GET variable is there and just add its own variable

### What I tried

```
    $("a.mypage").click(function()
    { 
           console.log("clicked"); 
           window.history.pushState("null", "null", "page/?var=Value of this Link"); 
    });
```

The problem with this approach is that it works when I click any link the first time, but when I click another link second time, it starts appending page name; something like this:-

`http://www.mylink.com/page/page?/var=Value of the Variable`

Comment: `window.location.href = window.location.href + "?var=Value";` is this helpful?

Comment: Change `"page/?var=Value of this Link"` to `"/page/?var=Value of this Link"`

Comment: `window.history.pushState("null", "null", window.location.href+"?variable=vaaar");` solution

Comment: GGG, your solutions worked perfectly!